# Averaging pandas pivot table by quarters

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas pivot table that I created that needs to be grouped by quarterly dates with the balance of each fico band per quarter added together. The quarters would be Q1 (Jan, Feb, March), Q2 (Apr, May, June), Q3 (July, Aug, Sep), and Q4 (Oct, Nov, Dec). Because I'm trying to automate this process I need to group by the quarters for different years, as well. For example, 2015 Q1, 2016 Q1, etc. The code I used to get this table was:

```
total_balance = df.pivot_table('balance','base_ts', 'fico_orig_band')

fico_orig_band  300-649 650-699 700-749 750-799 800-850 invalid missing
base_ts                         
2015-11-28      1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
2015-12-30      2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
2016-01-30      3000    3000    3000    3000    3000    3000    3000
2016-02-27      4000    4000    4000    4000    4000    4000    4000
2016-03-30      5000    5000    5000    5000    5000    5000    5000
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the non aggregated DataFrame?

Comment: `total_balance.groupby(total_balance.index.to_period('Q-MAR')).mean()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang be careful with means of means, if the number of items per day is different this will give a weighted mean ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dates to quarter before aggregation:

```
out = (df
 .assign(ts_band=pd.to_datetime(df['ts_band']).dt.to_period('Q-MAR'))
 .pivot_table('balance', 'base_ts', 'fico_orig_band')
)
```